# equalsIgnorecase is faling even though both actual & expected strings are same

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing problem in comparing two strings. Both the strings are same but still the condition is failing. Below is the screen shot of code & error I am getting.

[image]

Below is the code,

```
  public void validatePageHeader(String strExpectedPageHeader) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String strActualPageHeader = weHomePageHeader.getText();
        System.out.println("strExpectedPageHeader :"+strExpectedPageHeader);
        System.out.println("strActualPageHeader :"+strActualPageHeader);

        if(weHomePageHeader.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(strExpectedPageHeader)){
            System.out.println("Matched");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Matched");
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(strActualPageHeader, strExpectedPageHeader );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in validating page header "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the error shown in console.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Sanju\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1613164258\testng-   customsuite.xml

strExpectedPageHeader :Guru99 Bank
strActualPageHeader :Guru99 Bank
Not Matched
[Utils] Attempting to create F:\SeleniumPractice\Guru99Bank\test-  output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory F:\SeleniumPractice\Guru99Bank\test-output\Default suite   exists: true
PASSED: launchApp
FAILED: testLoginPageHeader("Guru99 Bank Home Page", "Guru99 Bank",  "mngr56592", "umYzehE")
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Guru99 Bank] but found [Guru99 Bank]
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:190)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:200)
at com.pageobjects.LoginPage.validatePageHeader(LoginPage.java:63)
at com.driver.Login.testLoginPageHeader(Login.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Maybe there's a non-breaking space instead of a normal space, perhaps even invisible (control) characters. Could you display the string in hex format?

Comment: I'd guess it may be some encoding issue. What is your browser encoding and what is your source code encoding ?

Comment: Please always show your code as text - we prefer code not to be added as images here, since it cannot be copy and pasted. Would you amend?

Comment: also could you please convert the two to the arrays of chars and print them? (after doing Arrays.toString). There might be characters which look the same / invisible

Comment: @Ivan Still not working. Below is my changes                                                           char[] charExpectedArray = strExpectedPageHeader.toCharArray();
   for(int i = 0;i<charExpectedArray.length;i++){
    System.out.print(charExpectedArray[i]);
   }                                                                                       System.out.println("Actual char Array");
   char[] charActualArray = strActualPageHeader.toCharArray();
   for(int i = 0;i<charActualArray.length;i++){
    System.out.print(charActualArray[i]);
   }

Comment: @SanjayDVG Please edit your question to add that code and the outputs of it. It gives me no info without the outputs and it's hard to read in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can try with .trim function it will work or send HTML piece where you are doing testing. You can try with:

```
String strActualPageHeader = weHomePageHeader.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("strExpectedPageHeader :"+strExpectedPageHeader);
        System.out.println("strActualPageHeader :"+strActualPageHeader);
        if(weHomePageHeader.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(strExpectedPageHeader)){
            System.out.println("Matched");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Matched");
        }
```